# How to set up W3SVC service Log On as Local User account

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8

For some security issue we must change `W3SVC` service `Log On` account.

I'm using `Windows Server 2012 R2`, `IIS` version is 8.5.

`IIS Admin Service` not installed because we not use FTP and SMTP.

I created user from `Computer Management` > `Local Users and Groups` > create user name `nobody` and password.

And go `Local Security Policy` > `Local Policies` > `User Rights Assignment` > `Log on as a service` > Add `nobody` account which i created before.

Run explorer move to `c:\inetpub` give all permission to `nobody` account.

Run `services.msc` > `World Wide Web Publishing Service` > `Log On` tab > Check `This account` > browse `nobody` account > `General` tab > `Stop` and `Start`

The problem is when `World Wide Web Publishing Service` restart then it shows error

`Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services`

I want to run `World Wide Web Publishing Service` non `localsystem` account. How can i do?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The application pool identity is what determines what your web apps run as.

Comment: @Appleoddity Beacuse of korea's security policy. Then Application pool is same as what i want to do?

Comment: See here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities